Как перевести кнопки в плагине Carbon Fields Wordpress?
Судя по всему в 3-ей версии плагина Carbon Fields есть проблема с переводом кнопок, не смотря на то, что файл перевода есть в папке плагина и язык в админке wordpress так же установлен на русский. Подскажите пжлст как решить проблему, если кто то сталкивался?


Попробуйте использовать плагин для локализации WordPress.
Плагин называется Loco translate
Ссылка:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/
Если вы установили carbon fields как плагин, то соответственно в меню плагина выбрать плагины затем название плагина(carbon fields) и добавить перевод на нужном языке.
Если установили как часть темы то вероятно в меню плагина -> Тема, и перевести тему, но вариант с подключением в теме loco translate не тестировал
